# How to express a Higher order identity function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to define a type which looks something like this:

```
export type HigherOrderIdentity<
  H extends object,
  F extends (s: H) => (...args: any[]) => H
> = F extends (s: H) => (...args: infer P) => H 
  ? (s: H) => (...args: P) => H
  : never;
```

The idea is that:

- I can create a higher order function where the first function is passed a known dictionary type `H`
- The next function can have ANY parameters but must return the same type `H`
- The parameters of the 2nd function are preserved in the type

This might be represented in code like so:

```
type TestDict = {foo?: number, bar?: string};

const t1: HigherOrderIdentity<TestDict> = () => ({});
const t2: HigherOrderIdentity<TestDict> = (foo: number) => ({foo});
const t3: HigherOrderIdentity<TestDict> = (foo: number, bar: string) => ({foo, bar});
```

The problem i'm having is that both generic parameters are required whereas I really need the second one to be *inferred*. As an alternative I had hoped to get this to work:

```
export type HigherOrderIdentity2<
  H extends object,
  F extends (s: H) => (...args: any[]) => H
> = (s: H) => (...args: Parameters<F>) => H;

const tt1: HigherOrderIdentity2<TestDict> = () => ({});
```

Sadly this fails in the same way. Is there any way to get TS's inference engine up to the task?

> I've added a [code playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=56&pln=22&pc=1#code/LAKA9AVBoAQTBBGALAlgc2QUwE4wPY4AmuMAZgK4B2AxgC6r5UwDuaNyMqAzjAA458AN1QkiMAIYwA1lXwtm3OhLpYYAHgASAPgA0seDxh1szHNWPJ8FTJPLV6jZm3wByXtwxUVFHGpoSzABGaoEAniaoVOgGMEEUdJYq9rQMTDAAthRKMH50vswmatwSGWpEKlJ0YXxqWtoGYKBYAB58hInVtTCaGNg4APLEuACSJFQM1eqwPTCtqlREvPhBAFZY9PogMDAAYnMtC0swABTcAFw9AJQwALzapwB0zxI46BeSVGEA2gC6N-ceqAHrc9gcjrwzpdNACHidno9Xu9LlEyKQAAqw2YzAD8pw+MLucIRSI+mKJQO2MEuVCwQlwAG5QMyQF01AAVLBKAAiqHodxgAG8yPh8DiaRQMiEcLo4q9xTAlDgougAL5MkCgGhMHJ0ACM0L6uCGJBwYywE1QU05PL5dBBpyxJ0FqquGu1VF1ACZDZhjcMzeNJmF1Da6Lz6A6TiL8BKpbgncLRa73TrOgBmX39E2jINWkNhiP2gXR0Vx6WyoKvS5KlWJmOV14plnNNodYw1NS9P2DAPmy3VL3TKmacEW44rdabGb7ebjyEEp0kt4fcJ-LGaYElxcU+EvFeXdGvUpYVQ4bjqXbaDcarVp4z6rP+0394NDwt2qOJlNAA) with the code samples above.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't support *partial type argument inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  As a workaround you can write curried generic functions that behave similarly... like [this code here](https://tsplay.dev/mbkbPW).  Does that meet your needs?  Like, can you use the resulting `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` as you expect?  If so, I'm happy to write up an answer.  If not, please elaborate on what the issue is.

Comment: Yes I think I can make this type of solution work for what I'm trying to solve.